# Why array is getting bigger after loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to change a color of background cells in google sheets so I wrote a code that I guess should do the job after putting into `.setBackgrounds()` (to mark duplicates)

But I have no idea why after looping `calkiemNowa` array is getting few times bigger then the original arrays.

Values length is around 4k and nowaArr has 200 elements, but the output `calkiemNowa` has something around 120k elements so I am getting error of too many values...

The goal seems to be simple: check if in the `Values` are the same elements as in `nowaArr` and mark them red.

Why `calkiemNowa` is getting that big? is it because of double loop?

```
    var nowaArr =[[1376064101], [1376064201], [1376613201], [1376613301], [1376613401], [1376613501], [1376613601], [1376613701], [1376613801], [1376613901], [1216987501], [1256524001], [1256639901], [1296132901], [1296133001], [1296133101], [1296133201]];
    var values = [[1326M76501], [1326M76301], [1326M76101], [1326M76901], [1326M76701], [1296133901], [1296133701], [1296133801], [1326H14201], [1216991801], [1236N12801], [1236F76701], [1326H16101], [1376616801], [1236F78101], [1236N13401], [1326G44401], [1236F79301], [1326848401], [1326N08801], [1326N08601], [1326N12601], [1326N09801], [1326N14701], [1326N15401], [1326N09601], [1326N09001], [1326N14001], [1326N11901],[1296133201]];

function checkArrays(){

var calkiemNowa = [];
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < nowaArr.length; j++){
    if(values[i][0] === nowaArr[j][0]){
      calkiemNowa.push('red');
    }else{
      calkiemNowa.push('null');
    }
  }
}
return calkiemNowa;
}
```

Comment: calkiemNowa  array size should be exactly nowaArr.length * values.length. each iteration you are pushing a value into the array and the iteration number is the length of nowaArr  multiply by the length of values . by this calculation, the final size of calkiemNowa  should be 800K. I guess it crashes before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it works, you can have it a try

```js
function checkArrays(){

var calkiemNowa = [];
loop1:
for(const value of values){
  loop2:
  for(const arr of nowaArr){
    if(value[0] === arr[0]){
      calkiemNowa.push('red');
      continue loop1;
    }
  }
  calkiemNowa.push(null);
}
return calkiemNowa;
}
```